# Login without email verification after registration in webmatrix

Tags: asp.net, webmatrix

I have setup a website using web pages (webmatrix) not MVC. I would like the user to be logged in after registration without having email verification, how can i make it happen ? I am asking this because my smtp is set up as WebMail.SmtpServer = "smtp.gmail.com"; and verification email either doesn't go to hotmil or live email or go very late, so it could be frustration for users. It goes to gmail quickly though,

So i decided that user could login without email verification, pls help me to do it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

WebSecurity.CreateAccount() method requires three parameters to create a membership account

- **userName**
- **password**
- **requireConfirmationToken**  [Optional parameter]

To create an account without an email verification by the user, simply set requireConfirmationToken = false. It is false by default. your code should look like this

```
WebSecurity.CreateAccount(email, password, false);
```

The code simply tells Websecurity Class not to expect a Token from user.